# Suggestions on creating document library for infopath with departmental hierarchy?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

I have one main site with many subsites.  Each subsite is basically a department within the organization.  I have a time card infopath form (with workflow) that everyone in the organization needs to fill out.  However, I want keep the form so that each department can only see within their own unit.  I know I can create a form library within each subsite, but that would make it a maintenance nightmare.  I just want to create the form under the main site and create links within each subsite.  When a user click on the link, it will take them to the central repository but I filter by the department or permissions?  I believe you can set some sort of permission that each department can view their own? user roles for the form?
Can someone point me to the right path?

Thanks,

Environment: SP2010,Sql server 2008, Office 2010

Answer (score 0):

After searching and searching,

One option if security is not a concern is just to use a custom view with filtering by Department and created by = [Me] or just simply by Department.

or if security is a concern:

[technet q/a](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/02f49445-e49a-495e-b0a0-693ca07c436d)